# Using regex "\1" in RegReplace

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I recently downloaded RegReplace for Sublime 3, and have been trying to use a regular expression to remove certain lines in a block of text. I used the find and replace terms stated below to set a rule in RegReplace.

```
find = "(D\).*\nE\).*\n)([ABCDE]\).*)\n*"
replace = "\1\n"


1)This is a paragraph of text

A) option 1
B) option 2
C) option 3
D) option 4
E) option 5

A) option 1
```

I am trying to remove the last "A) option 1". when this is run (ctrl-f), instead I end up with

```
1)This is a paragraph of text

A) option 1
B) option 2
C) option 3

SOL
```

Why isn't RegReplace recognising and applying the "\1"? And why does "SOL" appear?

Comment: so you just wanted to remove A),B)... from each line right?

Comment: Try `"\\1\n"`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `"\\1\n"`.

The point is that the regex is handled with Python, and inside regular string literals the backslash may form escape sequences. One of them is used by you, an LF symbol. The regex engine requires a *literal* backslash, and it can be defined as `"\\"`.